# Update Statement Using Max Date and userid as the criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, maxdate

So I am trying to Update a contract table where the Contract Start Date is the latest date and the relevant employee id. The Contract Table stores all past information about the employee.

eg.

```
contract_tbl
+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|Contractid  |EmployeeId  |ContractStartDate   |ContractEndDate  | Position      |
+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|   1        |   1        |  2012-12-13        |  2013-12-12     |  Data Entry   |
+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|   2        |   1        |  2014-01-26        |  2015-01-25     |  Data Entry   |
+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|   3        |   2        |  2014-01-26        |  2015-01-25     |  Data Entry   |
+------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

This is the SQL that I have but it does not work. (using a mysql db)

```
UPDATE contract_tbl 
SET Position='Data Analyst' 
WHERE EmployeeId = 1 And ContractStartDate= (
  select max(ContractStartDate 
  FROM contract_tbl))
```

So it should Update the second row shown above with Data Analyst in the Position column but I am getting an error.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *... but ... getting an error...* What error? Post it.

Comment: for just employee 1 or all employees?

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis after `MAX`.

Comment: Er... ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: this is the error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From contract))' at line 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will also do:

```
UPDATE contract_tbl a
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(ContractStartDate) m
  FROM contract_tbl
  WHERE EmployeeId = 1) b ON a.ContractStartDate = b.m AND a.EmployeeId = 1
SET a.Position='Data Analyst';
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably this is what you want:

```
UPDATE contract_tbl c1
SET Position='Data Analyst' 
WHERE EmployeeId = 1 And ContractStartDate= (
  SELECT max(ContractStartDate)
  FROM contract_tbl c2
  WHERE c2.EmployeeId = c1.EmployeeId
)
```